# Why can I not use my additional 10 votes on just questions.

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting

I voted 30 times on answers and questions, before reaching 30 votes. I cannot reach 40 votes. I beg the title.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Every day you are given **30** all-purpose votes and **10** questions-only votes. But once you are within **5** of either limit, the countdown 5..4..3..2..1 begins regardless of what you vote for. This means that in order to use all **40** votes, you must vote for at least **10** questions before your **25** th answer vote.

How could this be any simpler?

Comment: (In case this isn't clear, the sarcasm of last sentence wasn't directed at the OP.)

Answer (score 12):

It is by design. See [Cannot vote on question although 40 votes limit not reached](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90726/cannot-vote-on-question-although-40-votes-limit-not-reached)

In particular:

> If 1 in 3 of your votes are on questions, you will get 40 votes.
>
> If you vote on fewer questions than that you will get fewer votes (lowest is 30)

See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90256/155238