# About the badge Vox Populi

Tags: discussion, voting, badges

My case is opposite to the one post in [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3695/vox-populi-badge). I have used the 40 max votes yesterday and until now I have not received the Vox Populi badge. Are there any rules on how to distribute our votes per day? May I know some explanation? Thanks.
I don't know if its proper to tag this as bug.

Comment: Just checking: Did you actually get to 40 votes, or did you possibly hit [this wall](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10450/11619)? For example, at the moment your vote count for the day stands at 34. See also [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/8498/11619).

Comment: I find your question somewhat confusing. Yes, if you want to cast 40 votes a day you need to distribute them correctly, specifically you need to vote on questions enough. (Beyond that, no) Otherwise you max out somewhere between 30 and 40. For 30 you'd get suffrage, which you have. Can  you double check on your votes tab that you indeed have cast 40 votes. (It may also be that votes on posts that get deleted too soon will not count.)

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen I'm sure that was more than $30$. After, I can't cast votes anymore. In fact, in less than hour, I can vote again. Thanks for pointing the link. I found some rules there.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Yeah, I got it now. I got 34 total votes as I checked my votes cast. Thanks for sharing your time.

Comment: Where can you check your votes tab?

Comment: @TripleA In your activity tab menu, something like this http://math.stackexchange.com/users/44376/juniven?tab=votes, go to votes tab and press

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In the interest of having an answer, lifted from a comment.*

Yes, if you want to cast 40 votes a day you need to distribute them correctly, specifically you need to vote on questions enough. 
Otherwise, you max out somewhere between 30 and 40, and it appears this is what happened. For 30 votes one gets the Suffrage badge, which you have.

In particular, it is not necessarily enough to vote until one gets told one cannot vote anymore. Some more details are on [Why can I not use my additional 10 votes on just questions.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8498/why-can-i-not-use-my-additional-10-votes-on-just-questions)

Possibly this is vaguely a duplicate of this report.

Comment: Thank you for the summary. I'm just new to this meta and need to read many rules in here.

Comment: You are welcome. I think your question was fine. It's more a subtle point, and the dupe not all that direct.